# Split activity data into hours and get duration per hour

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have data about activities as below:

```
login_time          logout_time         a           b           c 
2018-03-01 08:15:20 2018-03-01 08:16:01 0.000000    0.000000    62
2018-03-01 08:16:28 2018-03-01 08:19:38 52.199083   21.000718   62
2018-03-01 08:57:10 2018-03-01 09:46:26 52.199083   21.000590   62
2018-03-01 10:05:43 2018-03-01 10:08:51 0.000000    0.000000    62
2018-03-02 09:45:40 2018-03-02 09:47:16 52.239281   21.010551   62
```

I need to calculate session durations (in seconds) split by date and hour, so the result should be similar to this:

```
a           b           c       duration hour   date
0.000000    0.000000    62.0    41.0    8.0     2018-03-01
52.199083   21.000718   62.0    190.0   8.0     2018-03-01
52.199083   21.000590   62.0    170.0   8.0     2018-03-01
52.199083   21.000590   62.0    2786.0  9.0     2018-03-01
0.000000    0.000000    62.0    188.0   10.0    2018-03-01
52.239281   21.010551   62.0    96.0    9.0     2018-03-02
```

As you can see, third line in source df was split into two rows in result df.
Sometimes logout_time can be the next day after login_time, which is additional issue.

I did it with the following code and it works, but as it iterates over rows, it is extremely slow. 
Files I operate on are over 1 mln rows, so any clue how to do it in more efficient will be welcomed.

```
def SplitAvail(df):
    new_split=pd.DataFrame()
    for i in np.arange(df.shape[0]):
        row=df.iloc[i,:]
        if (row.login_time.day==row.logout_time.day):
                new_split=new_split.append(MakeSplitAvail(row))
        else: 
            row1=row.copy()
            row1.logout_time=datetime(row.login_time.year,row.login_time.month,
                           row.login_time.day, 23,59,59)
            new_split=new_split.append(MakeSplitAvail(row1))
            row2=row.copy()
            row2.login_time=datetime(row.logout_time.year,row.logout_time.month,
                           row.logout_time.day, 0,0,0)
            new_split=new_split.append(MakeSplitAvail(row2))
    return new_split

def MakeSplitAvail(row):
    split=pd.DataFrame()
    for j in np.arange(row.login_time.hour, row.logout_time.hour+1,1):
        row_t=row.copy()
        h1=datetime(row.login_time.year,row.login_time.month,
                           row.login_time.day, j,0,0)
        h2=h1+ dt.timedelta(hours=1)
        row_t['hour']=j
        row_t['duration']=(min(row_t.logout_time, h2)-max(row_t.login_time, h1))\
            .total_seconds()
        split=split.append(row_t)
    return split
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer overview:

1. Make sample dataset
2. Add columns with duration, hour and date information
3. Process rows which need splitting
4. Merge split rows with non-split rows to generate the final result

#### 1. Make sample dataset

I set the starting date the same as your original data and used random number generators to make additional data. This takes about **40 ms** on my Macbook.

```
start = pd.Timestamp('2018-03-01 08:15:20').value
login_time = start + np.random.randint(10, 1000, size=100000).cumsum() * 10 ** 9
logout_time = login_time + np.random.lognormal(mean=6, size=100000) * 10 ** 9
df = pd.DataFrame({'login_time': pd.to_datetime(login_time), 
                   'logout_time': pd.to_datetime(logout_time).round(freq='s')})
```

The dataset has 100k records. About 82% require no splits, about 17% require one split and >1% requires 2+ splits. This can be changed by changing parameters/type of distribution used

```
df['hour_diff'].value_counts()

0     82309
1     17117
2       467
3        76
4        16
5         8
6         3
8         2
16        1
10        1
Name: hour_diff, dtype: int64
```

#### 2. Add columns with duration, hour, date information

This is relatively straightforward. There's no need to do pure Python iteration. The modulo operator `%` is used to fix negative hour differences when dates change. This takes about **1.4 s** on my Macbook.

```
df['duration'] = (df['logout_time'] - df['login_time']).apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds())
df['date'] = df['login_time'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
df['hour'] = df['login_time'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
df['hour_diff'] = (df['logout_time'].apply(lambda x: x.hour) - df['hour']) % 24
```

#### 3. Process rows which need splitting

This is the hard part. Here I used `itertuples` for relatively fast iteration over the dataframe. I place all record tuples in a list and build a new dataframe from that list. It is a very common mistake among newbies, but Pandas is terrible at iterative dataframe building, so I suggest you avoid that going forward. It's faster to make a list of records and then build a new dataframe from it. `process_record` is implemented as a generator function to make things a bit more elegant/efficient. This takes about **1.5 s** on my Macbook.

```
def process_record(t):
    cumtime = 0
    r = t._asdict()
    for i in range(t.hour_diff + 1):
        pseudo_logout = min(t.logout_time, pd.Timestamp(t.date) + pd.Timedelta(hours=t.hour + i + 1))
        duration = (pseudo_logout - t.login_time).total_seconds() - cumtime
        cumtime += duration
        r['duration'] = duration
        yield tuple(r.values())

records = []
for t in df[df['hour_diff'] > 0].itertuples():
    for r in process_record(t):
        records.append(r)
split_df = pd.DataFrame(records)
split_df = split_df.drop(0, axis=1)
split_df.columns = df.columns
```

#### 4. Merge split rows with non-split rows

Lastly, simply concatenate `split_df` with the unchanged records from `df`. This takes about **30 ms** on my Macbook:

```
merged_df = pd.concat([split_df, df[df['hour_diff'] == 0]])
merged_df = merged_df.sort_values(by='login_time').reset_index(drop=True)
```

The final result looks like this:

```
                login_time         logout_time  duration        date  hour  hour_diff
0      2018-03-01 08:21:29 2018-03-01 08:30:12     523.0  2018-03-01     8          0
1      2018-03-01 08:28:17 2018-03-01 08:42:47     870.0  2018-03-01     8          0
2      2018-03-01 08:33:17 2018-03-01 08:35:29     132.0  2018-03-01     8          0
3      2018-03-01 08:40:13 2018-03-01 08:45:50     337.0  2018-03-01     8          0
4      2018-03-01 08:45:12 2018-03-01 08:49:54     282.0  2018-03-01     8          0
5      2018-03-01 08:54:28 2018-03-01 09:01:19     332.0  2018-03-01     8          1
6      2018-03-01 08:54:28 2018-03-01 09:01:19      79.0  2018-03-01     8          1
7      2018-03-01 09:01:30 2018-03-01 09:03:06      96.0  2018-03-01     9          0
8      2018-03-01 09:04:01 2018-03-01 09:05:44     103.0  2018-03-01     9          0
9      2018-03-01 09:17:30 2018-03-01 09:46:40    1750.0  2018-03-01     9          0
10     2018-03-01 09:21:40 2018-03-01 09:22:31      51.0  2018-03-01     9          0
```

In total, this takes about 3s for 100k records on a single core (30 us/record). Results may vary depending on the number of records that need splitting, but I guess you should be able to comfortably process 1m+ records per minute.

I also made this available as a Jupyter notebook [here](https://gist.github.com/gusutabopb/8d2b99e6bb4031222215ccc7fd8c96ad).

Comment: Thanks, but it does not solve the issue of splitting longer session between hours. E.g. if you take the third row, in the output it should be split into two rows, so 2956 seconds should be divided into 170 secs in 8:00 and 2786 in 9:00

Comment: @Sigurd: Completely rewrote the answer. Please let me know if it does what you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. It shows me how much I still have to learn in python :) 
The only thing is that columns 'hour' and 'date' are now based on login_time. Small addition inside function process_record(t) just before 'yield' fixes this: 

`r['hour']=(t.hour+i)%24 `
`r['date']+=pd.Timedelta(days=((t.hour+i)//24)) `